# Error when using limit of sum as parameter

Tags: manipulate, summation

Here is my code so far, which works when I set an upper limit for the sum in F:

```
f[x_] = x^2
a[k_] := 2*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2*k*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]
b[k_] := 2*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2*k*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]
F[x_] = a[0] + 
  Sum[a[k - 1]*Cos[2*k - 1*Pi*x] + b[k]*Sin[2*k*Pi*x], {k, 1, 10}]
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I'm trying to plot F as a function of n, where n is the upper limit of the sum in F, so that I can use

```
Manipulate[Plot[F[x],{x,0,1}],{n,1,10}]
```

But when I try to use

```
F[x_] = a[0] + 
  Sum[a[k - 1]*Cos[2*k - 1*Pi*x] + b[k]*Sin[2*k*Pi*x], {k, 1, 10}]
Manipulate[Plot[F[x],{x,0,1}],{n,1,10}]
```

I get an error:

```
DifferenceRoot::ifprec: Parameters in DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY]$,\[FormalN]$},{Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>] \[FormalY]$[<<1>>]+Plus[<<5>>] \[FormalY]$[<<1>>]+Power[<<2>>] \[FormalY]$[<<1>>]==0,\[FormalY]$[2]==0,\[FormalY]$[3]==E^(4 I+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>])}]] are not exact numbers.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x^2;

a[0] = 2*Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}];
a[k_] = Assuming[Element[k, Integers],
  2*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2*k*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]]

(* 1/(k^2 π^2) *)

b[k_] = Assuming[Element[k, Integers],
  2*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2*k*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]]

(* -(1/(k π)) *)

F[x_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 a[0] + Sum[a[k - 1]*Cos[2*k - 1*Pi*x] + b[k]*Sin[2*k*Pi*x], {k, 1, n}]

Manipulate[Plot[F[x, n], {x, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {x, F}],
 {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]